# Datetime conversion in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have data collected from surveys with a lot of variations in dates:

```
    ID      Date
0   3786    2020-09-03 21:58:00 
1   3785    3/9/2020 21:48  
2   3784    2020-09-03 10:46:00 
3   3783    2020-09-03 08:31:00 
4   3781    2020-09-03 04:20:00
```

To standardise the date format, I used:

```
df.Date= pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

which returned:

```
0      2020-09-03 21:58:00
1      2020-03-09 21:48:00    (month date switched)
2      2020-09-03 10:46:00
3      2020-09-03 08:31:00
4      2020-09-03 04:20:00
5      2020-05-03 10:19:00
6      2020-05-03 01:05:00
```

and you can see that in row 1 the month and date have been switched. Is there a way to convert all dates systematically? If not, what should I do?

Comment: A quick look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) shows you can include `dayfirst=True` e.g. `pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 'dayfirst = True':

```
data = {'ID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Date' : ['2020-09-03 21:58:00', '3/9/2020 21:48 ', '2020-09-03 10:46:00 ', '2020-09-03 08:31:00 ', '2020-09-03 04:20:00 ']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst = True)
display(df)
```

Result:

```
    ID  Date
0   1   2020-09-03 21:58:00
1   2   2020-09-03 21:48:00
2   3   2020-09-03 10:46:00
3   4   2020-09-03 08:31:00
4   5   2020-09-03 04:20:00
```

Answer (score 1):

- Just provide **format** and **errors** parameters in this function
  as described in [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)